# how to place a stop-buy order by ccxt in binance

Tags: binance, ccxt

I try to do that by codes below but I got error

```
import ccxt  # noqa: E402
import apiConfig

exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': apiConfig.API_KEY,
    'secret': apiConfig.API_SECRET,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})

symbol = 'RVN/USDT'

type = 'limit'  # or 'market', other types aren't unified yet
side = 'buy'
amount = 69  # your amount
price = 0.21  # your price
# overrides
params = {
    'stopPrice': 0.20,  # your stop price
    'type': 'stopLimit',
}
order = exchange.create_order(symbol, type, side, amount, price, params)
```

I got this error:
ccxt.base.errors.BadRequest: binance {"code":-1106,"msg":"Parameter 'stopPrice' sent when not required."}

Answer (score 4):

The ccxt documentation is incorrect in this case (stop limit on Binance, might work with other exchanges).

You need to set the `type` argument as `stop_loss_limit` or `take_profit_limit` (depending on whether `price` is greater/less than `stopPrice`). Also, the `params.type` doesn't override the `type` value.

```
type = 'stop_loss_limit'

params = {
    'stopPrice': 0.20,
}
```

Binance API ([docs](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#new-order--trade)) accepts the `stopPrice` param only when the `type` is one of the following:

- STOP_LOSS
- STOP_LOSS_LIMIT
- TAKE_PROFIT
- TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT

And ccxt ([GitHub source](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/python/ccxt/binance.py#L1805)) sets the `uppercaseType` only from the function argument `type` and does not override the value from `params`.